# Manage targets with CMake and CLion

Tags: build, cmake, clion

Hi I'm new to CMake and all that stuff.

I try to set up an Project with imgui and OpenGL. 
My Project builds and works fine, but CLion shows all the GLFW examples and GoogleTests as Target.

[image]

I clone and build GLFW with these CMakeList:

CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

#download and build glew
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in glfw-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for glfw failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for glfw failed: ${result}")
endif()

#add dir
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)


add_executable(gbadbgCLI main.cpp)

#imgui
target_sources(gbadbgCLI PRIVATE imgui/imgui.cpp imgui/imgui_draw.cpp imgui/imgui_impl_opengl2.cpp imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp imgui/imgui_demo.cpp)

# link packages
target_link_libraries(gbadbgCLI gbadbgLIB)
target_link_libraries(gbadbgCLI OpenGL::GL)
target_link_libraries(gbadbgCLI glfw)
```

CMakeLists.txt.in

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(glfw-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(glfw PREFIX glfw
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG 3.3.2

    SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-src"
    BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw-build"

    UPDATE_COMMAND ""

    CMAKE_ARGS
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>"
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
        "-DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF"
        "-DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF"
        "-DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF"

    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"

    LOG_DOWNLOAD 1 LOG_UPDATE 1 LOG_CONFIGURE 1 LOG_BUILD 1 LOG_INSTALL 1
)
```

Is there an easy way I can remove this targets?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is known problem
[CPP-14899 CLion creates "Application" run configurations for gtest targets when gtest 1.8.1 is used](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14899)

But it has work around:

Please,

- set the registry (`Help | Find Action... | Actions | Registry...`) value `cidr.test.framework.targetTypeFromHeaderDetectionEnable` to `true` ([v])
- close project
- remove `.idea` folder
- open project